# Redis endless requests workers.restart_requested_timestamp and /tmp/kdevtmpfsi

Tags: docker, symfony, redis, alpine-linux

I use docker `Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89` with docker compose `docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306` and I use redis image for store cache and others. When I entered in redis container and started MONITOR comand I faced with endless requests, do you know what is it and this is normal behaviour for redis ?

```
1586967988.436843 [0 172.19.0.7:40238] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
1586967988.871148 [0 172.19.0.7:40252] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
1586967989.445710 [0 172.19.0.7:40238] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
1586967989.891562 [0 172.19.0.7:40252] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
1586967990.454699 [0 172.19.0.7:40238] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
1586967990.909510 [0 172.19.0.7:40252] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
1586967991.464312 [0 172.19.0.7:40238] "MGET" "ikbkr16GHQ:workers.restart_requested_timestamp"
```

I used to build `image: redis:alpine` and `redis:5.0.8` and faced with the same behavior

```
redis:
    container_name: container_redis
    image: redis:5.0.8
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
    networks:
        - php
```

In my applicaiton (Symfony) I configured cace for redis with port like this

```
framework:
    cache:
    prefix_seed: minimoj/minimoj_be
    # Redis
    app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: redis://redis:6379
```

In locally this MGET request don't created problem for me, but on test server all six CPU loading on 100%, I don't know dependeies it from redis or not, but in htop monitor on test server all CPU's wasting by power with `Command` - `/tmp/kdevtmpfsi`. I researched info about that and recomendation was be remove `/tmp/kdevtmpfsi` from redis container. But it's not helped, after some cached executed, CPU loaded again to top. I don't know, maybe it's two question about `/tmp/kdevtmpfsi` and endless requests, but maybe they dependecies from each other

I run my consumer by supervisor

```
[program:messenger-consume]
command=php /var/www/symfony/bin/console messenger:consume success andraction_parse_row_success --limit=100
numprocs=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
```

**UPDATE**

I resolved problem with CPU loading, it was opened port(6379) in firewall for redis in outside and some malicious scripts parsed it and use. Now only what left this is `restart_requested_timestamp` request. Could you explain me this is corrct behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Symfony\Component\Messenger\Worker\StopWhenRestartSignalIsReceived
```

Symfony messanger component just checking if messenger:stop-worker command was fired. It looking for **restart_requested_timestamp** cache key and if that key exists consumer will stop its work.

Maybe this is about numprocs. How many consumers do you start?

Comment: I updated question. I run my consumer by supervisor with `numprocs=2`, from documetation, in this case I have two instance my worker

Comment: This is mine command `command=bash -c 'sleep 60 && /usr/local/bin/php -d memory_limit=128M /app/bin/console messenger:consume commands -t 300 -vv'. `You can try to add memory_limit and -t 300 it means that after 300sec it will stop

Comment: 1586967988.436843  
1586967988.871148
1586967989.445710
1586967989.891562
1586967990.454699
1586967990.909510
1586967991.464312

every second you get 2 MGET requests it's not big deal i think. You can try to remove one consumer and check cpu loading with only 1 MGET request per second

Comment: I resolved problem with CPU loading, it was opened port for redis in outside. Now only what left this is `restart_requested_timestamp`. Could you explain me this is corrct behaviour ?

Comment: Today i got this task to add redis cache and got the same question you have. So, you can check this class **StopWhenRestartSignalIsReceived->shouldRestart** method. Every 1 sec this method is fired, it checks if cache has 'workers.restart_requested_timestamp' key, the consumer will be stopped if this key exists and the value(timestamp) is greater than was timestamp when consumer was started.
When you use messenger:stop-workers command current timestamp value will be written to cache as 'workers.restart_requested_timestamp'. And your every-second-check will see it and will stop the consumer

Comment: need only one time execute `messenger:stop-workers`, correct ?

Comment: 1. You run `messenger:stop-workers`
2. Current timestamp was written to cache as `restart_requested_timestamp`
3. `StopWhenRestartSignalIsReceived->run`, this method will check that cache value exists and will stop(or reload i'm not sure) consumer.